# Bigquery Java API queries are smaller than the documented limit

Tags: google-bigquery

I am doing a request on a BigQuery table which is supposed to return around 11K rows. However, I cannot get more than 2400 rows in one GetQueryResultsResponse, the other rows must be accessed through paging.

I checked the doc, and it says that the response can be as big as 64K rows or 10M JSON, and my responses are way below that (1M JSON and 2400 rows), so I don't understand why my results are paged.

Is there a hidden parameter in the Java API that limits the number of rows ?

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the `maxResults` parameter that is described [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/getQueryResults?hl=ar)? It looks like the docs are a bit misleading on this front, since they indicate we return the max size by default. In order to save bandwidth, we only return 512 rows by default. This is based on the assumption that most people aren't really interested in the entire result, and if they are, they can use the `maxResults` parameter or page through the results.

Comment: Hey Jordan, thank you for your answer. I actually configured the maxResults to 64000 rows, but it did not change anything, the total result was still 2400 rows.

To make sure I was using the API correctly, I tested with values <2400, and it actually sent me the good number of rows (eg 2000).

Still, no way to go over 2400.

Comment: To check if it was related to the Java API, I used OAuth playground and CURL to do the same query, and I encounter exactly the same behavior : I am unable to go over 2935 rows.

The uncompressed response size is 3.9M on Windows.

Comment: The 2935 rows are 3.9MB? If so, then this may not be surprising. We use an approximate value when we compute the result size (in order to cap it at 10MB), and we round up to the worst case encoding. I'll investigate to see if our calculation is being more pessimistic than necessary.